# Unused argument at mean() & var()

Tags: r, statistics

I looked through a few Questions here, but I couldn't find any answer to my problem. So brief question:

For the following 2 operations:

- `mean(c(2,4))`
- `var(c(2,4))`

I got the following error:

> Error in c(2, 4) : unused argument (4)

What confuses me is that it works for my classmate.

Comment: It seems that you may have renamed the `c` function. Try this code from a fresh version of R.

Answer (score 0):

I gues it has something to do with your Packages.... Try this: `stats::var(c(2,4))`

Comment: Wrong function to isolate - `4` isn't an argument to `var`, it's an argument to `c`. Using `base::c` should work.